# installing lib called pip install psycopg2 but am getting error. windows 10

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

> PS F:\backup\PycharmProjects\Ecommerce\ecommerce> pip install
> psycopg2-binary Collecting psycopg2-binary   Using cached
> psycopg2-binary-2.8.6.tar.gz (384 kB) Using legacy 'setup.py install'
> for psycopg2-binary, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
> Installing collected packages: psycopg2-binary
> Running setup.py install for psycopg2-binary ... error
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> command: 'c:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\python.exe'
> -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\maddy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6rz34xts\psycopg2-binary\setup.py'"'"';
> **file**='"'"'C:\Users\maddy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6rz34xts\psycopg2-binary\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
> '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> install --record
> 'C:\Users\maddy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ha5485o1\install-record.txt'
> --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\Include\psycopg2-binary'
> cwd: C:\Users\maddy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6rz34xts\psycopg2-binary
> Complete output (183 lines):
> running install
> running build
> running build_py
> creating build
> creating build\lib.win32-3.9
> creating build\lib.win32-3.9\psycopg2
> copying lib\compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\psycopg2
> copying lib\errorcodes.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\psycopg2
> copying lib\errors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\psycopg2
> copying lib\extensions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\psycopg2
> copying lib\extras.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\psycopg2
> copying lib\pool.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\psycopg2
> copying lib\sql.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\psycopg2
> copying lib\tz.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\psycopg2
> copying lib_ipaddress.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\psycopg2
> copying lib_json.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\psycopg2
> copying lib_lru_cache.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\psycopg2
> copying lib_range.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\psycopg2
> copying lib_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\psycopg2
> running build_ext
> building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
> creating build\temp.win32-3.9
> creating build\temp.win32-3.9\Release
> creating build\temp.win32-3.9\Release\psycopg
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe
> /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec
> pq3 ext) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120004
> -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -I. -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/12/include -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/12/include/server -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um
> -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcpsycopg\adapter_asis.c
> /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.9\Release\psycopg\adapter_asis.obj
> adapter_asis.c
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe
> /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec
> pq3 ext) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120004
> -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -I. -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/12/include -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/12/include/server -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um
> -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcpsycopg\adapter_binary.c
> /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.9\Release\psycopg\adapter_binary.obj
> adapter_binary.c
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe
> /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec
> pq3 ext) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120004
> -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -I. -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/12/include -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/12/include/server -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um
> -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcpsycopg\adapter_datetime.c
> /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.9\Release\psycopg\adapter_datetime.obj
> adapter_datetime.c
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe
> /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec
> pq3 ext) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120004
> -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -I. -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/12/include -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/12/include/server -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include -IC:\Program

> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um
> -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcpsycopg\bytes_format.c
> /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.9\Release\psycopg\bytes_format.obj
> bytes_format.c
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe
> /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec
> pq3 ext) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120004
> -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -I. -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/12/include -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/12/include/server -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um
> -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe
> /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec
> pq3 ext) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120004
> -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -I. -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/12/include -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/12/include/server -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um
> -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcpsycopg\connection_type.c
> /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.9\Release\psycopg\connection_type.obj
> connection_type.c
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe
> /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec
> pq3 ext) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120004
> -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -I. -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/12/include -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/12/include/server -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um
> -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcpsycopg\conninfo_type.c
> /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.9\Release\psycopg\conninfo_type.obj
> conninfo_type.c
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe
> /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec
> pq3 ext) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120004
> -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -I. -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/12/include -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/12/include/server -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um
> -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcpsycopg\cursor_int.c
> /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.9\Release\psycopg\cursor_int.obj
> cursor_int.c
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe
> /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec
> pq3 ext) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120004
> -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -I. -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/12/include -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/12/include/server -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um
> -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcpsycopg\cursor_type.c
> /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.9\Release\psycopg\cursor_type.obj
> cursor_type.c
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe
> /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec
> pq3 ext) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120004
> -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -I. -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/12/include -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/12/include/server -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um
> -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcpsycopg\diagnostics_type.c
> /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.9\Release\psycopg\diagnostics_type.obj
> diagnostics_type.c
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe
> /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec
> pq3 ext) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120004
> -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -I. -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/12/include -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/12/include/server -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um
> -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcpsycopg\error_type.c
> /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.9\Release\psycopg\error_type.obj
> error_type.c
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe
> /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec
> pq3 ext) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120004
> -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -I. -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/12/include -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/12/include/server -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um
> -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcpsycopg\green.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.9\Release\psycopg\green.obj
> green.c
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe
> /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec
> pq3 ext) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120004
> -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -I. -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/12/include -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/12/include/server -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um
> -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcpsycopg\libpq_support.c
> /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.9\Release\psycopg\libpq_support.obj
> libpq_support.c
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe
> /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec
> pq3 ext) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120004
> -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -I. -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/12/include -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/12/include/server -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um
> -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcpsycopg\lobject_int.c
> /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.9\Release\psycopg\lobject_int.obj
> lobject_int.c
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe
> /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec
> pq3 ext) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120004
> -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -I. -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/12/include -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/12/include/server -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um
> -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcpsycopg\lobject_type.c
> /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.9\Release\psycopg\lobject_type.obj
> lobject_type.c
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe
> /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec
> pq3 ext) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120004
> -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -I. -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/12/include -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/12/include/server -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um
> -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcpsycopg\microprotocols.c
> /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.9\Release\psycopg\microprotocols.obj
> microprotocols.c
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe
> /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec
> pq3 ext) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120004
> -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -I. -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/12/include -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/12/include/server -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um
> -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcpsycopg\microprotocols_proto.c
> /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.9\Release\psycopg\microprotocols_proto.obj
> microprotocols_proto.c
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe
> /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec
> pq3 ext) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120004
> -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -I. -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/12/include -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/12/include/server -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um
> -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcpsycopg\notify_type.c
> /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.9\Release\psycopg\notify_type.obj
> notify_type.c
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe
> /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec
> pq3 ext) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120004
> -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -I. -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/12/include -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/12/include/server -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um
> -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcpsycopg\pqpath.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.9\Release\psycopg\pqpath.obj
> pqpath.c
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe
> /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec
> pq3 ext) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120004
> -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -I. -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/12/include -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/12/include/server -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um
> -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcpsycopg\psycopgmodule.c
> /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.9\Release\psycopg\psycopgmodule.obj
> psycopgmodule.c
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe
> /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec
> pq3 ext) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120004
> -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -I. -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/12/include -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/12/include/server -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um
> -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcpsycopg\replication_connection_type.c
> /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.9\Release\psycopg\replication_connection_type.obj
> replication_connection_type.c
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe
> /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec
> pq3 ext) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120004
> -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -
> -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcpsycopg\utils.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.9\Release\psycopg\utils.obj
> utils.c
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe
> /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec
> pq3 ext) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120004
> -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -I. -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/12/include -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/12/include/server -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um
> -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcpsycopg\win32_support.c
> /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.9\Release\psycopg\win32_support.obj
> win32_support.c
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe
> /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec
> pq3 ext) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120004
> -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -Ic:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include -I. -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/12/include -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/12/include/server -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um
> -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcpsycopg\xid_type.c

> ```
> connection_type.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PQtransactionStatus
> connection_type.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PQbackendPID
> connection_type.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PQconninfo
> conninfo_type.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PQsslInUse
> conninfo_type.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PQconnectionNeedsPassword
> conninfo_type.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PQpass
> conninfo_type.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PQdb
> conninfo_type.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PQsslAttribute
> conninfo_type.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PQport
> conninfo_type.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PQoptions
> conninfo_type.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PQconnectionUsedPassword
> conninfo_type.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PQsslAttributeNames
> conninfo_type.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PQuser
> conninfo_type.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PQhost
> cursor_type.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PQgetvalue
> cursor_type.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PQgetisnull
> cursor_type.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PQnfields
> cursor_type.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PQgetlength
> ```

> ```
> pqpath.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PQgetCopyData
> pqpath.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PQftable
> pqpath.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PQftype
> pqpath.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PQresultErrorMessage
> pqpath.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PQexec
> pqpath.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PQfmod
> pqpath.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PQcmdTuples
> pqpath.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PQntuples
> pqpath.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PQresStatus
> pqpath.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PQputCopyEnd
> ```

> ```
> ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> ```
>
> 'c:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\python.exe'
> -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\maddy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vec77xzn\psycopg2-binary\setup.py'"'"';
> **file**='"'"'C:\Users\maddy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vec77xzn\psycopg2-binary\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
> '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> install --record
> 'C:\Users\maddy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-kkineo_g\install-record.txt'
> --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\maddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\Include\psycopg2-binary'
> Check the logs for full command output.enter code here

Answer (score 0):

try this the real powershell (win+R and type powershell) `pip3 install psycopg2-binary` and disable your antivurus.

Comment: i have tried this one also but no use. Facing same issue bro.. i dont knoe whether it will be solved or not..

Comment: made it that it shoud function. PS: your output is overwalming.

Comment: got solution.. i installed python 32 bit then changed 64 bit it solved..